# WordPress: front-page.php, linking to the main homepage

Tags: wordpress

So I have a website where a custom front page needed to be built as a static page, to do this I created front-page.php

I believe the original homepage just showed a list of posts.

The issue that I am having is that I want to link the front-page.php to the original front page of the website. I've had a look at using home.php and setting the URL on the front-page.php file to `<?php echo get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ); ?>` but this just seemed to link to a single blog post.

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _I want to link the front-page.php to the original front page of the website._ What does this mean? `get_option('page_for_posts')` gives you the `id` of the page you set as the "blog" page in settings. `index.php` is the page that, by default, lists the posts.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings` > `Reading` and check off `A static page`, Below it select `Home` as the `Homepage`. That should do the trick.